# How to properly add code in comment

Tags: support, comments, formatting, code-formatting

How can I properly add a line of code in a comment like this

```
test test
```

I like it more grey than `test test` if that is possible.

Or if there is another way to define code in a comment to make it more clear I'd like to hear it.

Comment: The [formatting help page](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting) has a “Comment Formatting” section.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In *comments* you are limited to just `test test` which is generated by the code:

```
`test test`
```

There is no way to get the larger code bar like in your example or in the line above this in a *comment*.  This is because the comment system doesn't work *at all* with line breaks, etc. which the code bars like the above need.

Comment: I think it can be generalized, there are no format options to control line breaks or paragraphs, which also makes code blocks impossible and allows only inline code.

Comment: Is there a way to add it another way ? bold or italic or more darker background

Comment: @An0n *why*?  Adding that effect is just going to be more 'nuisance-like' to others rather than just be a straight `code line`.  If you're trying to share *that much code* that you need a code bar like in the question in a comment, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: I just see when other people for example set ` sudo apt-get update ` i see it more clear then when i wrote the same comment. Thats why im asking. And offcourse if i add allot of code i just answer the question.

Comment: @An0n Then that's an issue with how you see it.  It looks pretty clear on this side... unfortunately.  It's pretty clearly *not* standard comment code on the standard site stylesheets